# What is the difference between input function and eval function on python

Tags: python, python-3.5

I don't have o picture but I am asking did question because I am a beginner using python

Comment: one is good, one is evil. :)

Comment: What is eval used 4 and Wat is input used 4 ,it's confusing me

Comment: eval() is used to evaluate an expression and input() is used to take user input.

Comment: Can u give me an image of the two in operation so that I can understand it better

Answer (score 2):

`input()` takes user input as a string. It's very safe.

```
>>> usr = input('Enter some input: ')
Enter some input: hello, world
>>> usr
"hello, world"
```

`eval()` will execute a string as if it were python code. It's very dangerous.

```
>>>eval(input('Make it happen!'))
Make it happen! print('hello')
hello
>>>eval(input('Make it happen!'))
Make it happen! os.system('echo malicious things')
```

And now you've really messed up your computer.

Answer (score 1):

`eval()` is used to evaluate an expression and `input()` is used to take user input. Here are the examples:

```
#evaluates expression
>> eval('5+2')
>> 7
# Takes user input
>> input()
10 (user enters)
>> 10

#evaluates user input
>> eval('input()')
15 (user enters)
>> 15
```

Comment: You could also mention that `input` always returns a string even if it looks like a number is typed in.